# Get IP address of camera

Tags: network, ip, network-scanners

Is it possible to get the *global* IP address of a nearby camera?

For example, an IP camera is connected to a network, but you are not on that network, and cant get access for whatever reason) but you are nearby the camera. You want to find the login page for that camera. The login in page is accessible from the internet not just local network.

Comment: Being physically close to a device does not help you figure out the networking info of the device.

Comment: This is an ambiguous question.  I can argue that by looking at the camera model label, I can look for the documentation and assume the default IP of the camera by assuming whoever configure it doesn't change it.

Comment: sorry yeah I mean the global IP not the local, so basically an attacker is able to find the login page for example only by being within proximity of the camera (not connected to the same network, just in same area)

Comment: the attacker is trying to gain access to the login page for example of a nearby camera ... Or imagine there is a WIFI router nearby, can I determine the global IP of a device connected to that network without being connected to the same network?

Comment: So, you want to know the Internet IP address of a device that you happen to be physically near and not connecting to the network it is on? As I say, just being physically near does nothing for you.

Comment: @schroeder yeah. so the short answer is no. I know there are some techniques to get like the MAC address using Airmon-ng, wireshark, etc... Or even techniques for scanning for wireless devices in a room using these "bug detector" type devices, but I was wondering if using something like wireshark you could some how find the global IP of the device... Which it makes since that no, you cant.

Comment: I take that back, being near something and using a radio you can gain some information...

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of IP addresses, a local, private address, and a public , global address. A public address is the one that you can use *outside* the local network to connect to it, and its private address is what is used on the network. Private addresses start with 10., 192., and 172/173.

A camera is usually part of a network, either saving the feed to a local computer, and/or networked with other cameras. This way someone is able to monitor the device. However, in recent years smart cameras have become more popular, growing with the IoT boom. These cameras can be wireless, connecting to a local access point, they can store data on the device itself, usually by using an SD card, and can be accessed over the internet through a web portal.

The security issue with IoT cameras is pretty obvious, if you can gain access to its web portal, you can potentially brute-force the password, (many people don't even change the default login details, a quick google of the camera brand can get you that info), or if you have a wireless card that provides monitor mode you could perform a deauth attack, and get it to connect to your own network, either to gain details about the device itself, or the contents of the feed.

If the camera is *not* a smart camera however, it usually means that it is on a wired network, and only accessible by gaining access to the machine that is monitoring it. This presents its own, separate series of challenges.

So to answer your question, we have two main scenarios, which depend on whether the camera is wireless or not. If it is wireless, then yes you can potentially gain access directly to the camera itself, either through a deauth attack or over the web. If the camera is *not* wireless, then yes it can still be accessed, but that would require gaining to the machine monitoring the camera(s).

Both of these methods have legal implications of course, so check with local laws and gain permission where necessary.

If you need more info on anything leave a comment and I'll update this response to reflect further questions.

Comment: yeah this is exactly what I am asking, basically can attacker gain access to the login page without being connected to the same network as the camera. The attacker is for example in the same room, but doesn't have access to the camera's network... Basically is the camera broadcasting any information about its WAN IP or is there any way to figure that out?

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered about this for a long time, and think that perhaps through methods as described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N1C3WB8c0o) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N1C3WB8c0o) this could maybe 
 be possible.

Basically it seems by using a radio you could theoretically recreate someones screen, log key strokes, and maybe even recreate sections of memory, just by looking at radio interference.

Like whats described here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_(codename)